# Cassandra Database with Dummy Data

Tags: cassandra

I was wondering if there is an existing Cassandra database with like 500k records. I am asking this because I'd like to see how Cassandra performs.

Comment: I don't think there is any dummy db of this much records. But you can create this kind of record by using bulk insertion and doing something like `for(int =0;i<10000;i{insert record }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not.

However, you can use cassandra-stress tool to generate such a database easily, even with your schema and appropriate data distribution:
[Improved Cassandra 2.1 Stress Tool: Benchmark Any Schema – Part 1](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improved-cassandra-2-1-stress-tool-benchmark-any-schema)